# Why is the coefficient of determination maximized by OLS?

Tags: regression, linear

I've read that R^2 is maximized by OLS. Why is that the case and what exactly does that mean?
I really appreciate any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the definition of R squared.  It looks like

$$ R^2 = 1 - {\sum (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 \over \sum (y_i - \bar{y})^2}$$

The bottom term is fixed; it can not change.  The only thing which can change as a function of model coefficients is the top term $\sum (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 $, where $\hat{y} = X\beta$ is the prediction from OLS. If you do a little math, you can show that the coefficients obtained via OLS minimize this quantity, and hence they make $R^2$ maximal.

Comment: I love you! Thanks alot